# Java api for calculating Interquartile range

Tags: java

Is there any java api for calculating interquartile range? I was wondering apache commons math library contains all the stats function like mean, median, mode but i could not find any thing for IQR.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can use getPercentile from [DescriptiveStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html) class of Apache Commons Math, like in the following code sample.

```
double[] data = // obtain data here
DescriptiveStatistics da = new DescriptiveStatistics(data);
double iqr = da.getPercentile(75) - da.getPercentile(25);
```